# Read data from JSON, manipulate it and write it back in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a small JSON file with this content

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1111,
      "name": "Foo",
      "gold": 2
    },{
      "id": 2222,
      "name": "Bar",
      "gold": 7
    }
  ]
}
```

and when using Ajax I call this route

```
app.get('/incG/:id', function (req, res) {
  fs.writeFile('./database.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data); // get the data
    var users = json.users; // get all users
    var user = users.find(u => u.id === Number(req.params.id)); // get a user by id
    user.gold++; // increase his gold value
    res.send(user.gold); // send a response to the client
  });
});
```

when running the server I get this error message

```
undefined:1
utf8
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at ... \app.js:23:21
    at tryToString (fs.js:449:3)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:436:12)
```

How can I get the data from the file, change the specific object, selected by its id, write it back to the file and send a response to the client?

My code seems to be wrong, I want to use `writeFile` **not** `readFile`. I don't want to read the data, I want to manipulate it.

---

**EDIT**

I tried building up this code

```
app.get('/incG/:id', function (req, res) {
  var database = './database.json';
  var userId = Number(req.params.id);
  fs.readFile(database, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    var users = json.users;
    var user = users.find(u => u.id === userId);
    user.gold++;
    fs.writeFile(database, json, (err) => {
      res.send(user.gold);
    });
  });
});
```

but I think passing in `json` as a data object is wrong. The file content gets "destroyed"

Comment: isnt that readfile instead of writefile

Comment: hm yes, I am new to this. I want to use `writeFile`

Comment: first readfile, get all contents; parse it as per your wish and then writefile

Comment: Surely the problem is as the message suggests that 'u' is not defined in the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to write into a file, simply follow the node documentation:

```
app.get('/incG/:id', function (req, res) {
  fs.writeFile('./database.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {

    var users = json.users; // get all users
    var user = users.find(u => u.id === Number(req.params.id));
    user.gold++; // increase his gold value

    fs.writeFile('database.json', myJSON, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.send(user.gold);
    });
});
```

A better approach when reading from a file / writing to a file on a web server is to use `streams`, this way you will not consume a lot of memory doing the operation.

You can read more about it here in this great post:

- https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93
- https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93

Comment: Sorry, this is new to me, I want to use `writeFile` do you have an example for me? My code seems to be wrong, I just want to write data to the JSON file

Comment: ah, your question clearly states `read data` so please update it accordingly. I will update my answer.

Comment: sorry, would you mind explaining `src.pipe(manipulateData).pipe(res);` to me?

Comment: read the article I linked, it explains things greater details than a small comment on stackoverflow. Think of streams as chunks of data, but they dont have to be available all at once, you can send them in chunks per consumer demand.

Comment: for your small JSON object, i think its OK to simple write the file without streams, its just good to know about streams in general! happy learning.

Comment: would you mind explaining me the second parameter `myJSON`? Is it the whole new file?

Comment: `myJSON` is the stringified object you want to save. the snippet you have in the top og the question wrapped with `JSON.stringify`

Comment: I just went for a new topic but the first answer might not help. I just write down the new object and delete the rest of the data. Maybe you can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47508495/updating-content-from-json-files-by-using-the-filesystem-module-in-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're using `writeFile` wrongly. According to [Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback), the second argument to `writeFile` should be the data you want to write. See below:

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node.js', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The file has been saved!');
});
```

Comment: thank you, but where do I specify, which data I want to manipulate?