# Updating content from JSON files by using the filesystem module in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a small JSON file

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1111,
      "name": "Foo",
      "gold": 2
    },{
      "id": 2222,
      "name": "Bar",
      "gold": 7
    }
  ]
}
```

and want to manipulate the data of one specific object, selected by its id.

I want to

- read the data from the file
- manipulate the data
- write the **new** data back to the file
- send a response to the client

so I went for this route, called by using Ajax

```
app.get('/incG/:id', function (req, res) {

  fs.readFile('./database.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data); // Read the data
    var users = json.users; // Get all users
    var user = users.find(u => u.id === Number(req.params.id)); // get the user by id

    user.gold++; // increase his value

    fs.writeFile('./database.json', , (err) => { // the second parameter is missing!
      res.send(user.gold); // send a response to the client
    });
  });
});
```

As you can see, when using `fs.writeFile(database, , (err) => {` the second parameter is missing.

What do I have to pass in there? I just want to update one specific user object (one specific value).

---

**EDIT**

When passing in `JSON.stringify(user)` as a parameter I delete all the data in the file and just write down the new object. So this might not work this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
fs.readFile('./database.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data); // Read the data
    var users = json.users; // Get all users
    var userGold;
    users.find(u => {
        if (u.id === Number(req.params.id)) {
            userGold = u.gold++;
        }
    });
    users = JSON.stringify(users);
    fs.writeFile('./database.json', users, (err) => {
         res.send(userGold);
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry, this will just write down `[{"id":2312,"name":"Garzec","gold":3}]` to my JSON file

Comment: No it will update only the user with the match. did you tried it?

Comment: yes it does but the JSON file will be modified wrongly instead of having `{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1111,
      "name": "Foo",
      "gold": 2
    },{
      "id": 2222,
      "name": "Bar",
      "gold": 7
    }
  ]
}` I just have `[{"id":1111,"name":"Foo","gold":3}]` left

Comment: No way that should not be possible I tried it's working as expected. You should try copy and paste the above code.

Answer (score 0):

> [**`fs.writeFile(file, data[, options], callback)`**](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)

Pass stringified JSON as second argument.

```js
app.get('/incG/:id', function(req, res) {

  fs.readFile('./database.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data); // Read the data
    var users = json.users; // Get all users
    var user = users.find(u => u.id === Number(req.params.id)); // get the user by id

    user.gold++; // increase his value
    var dataToWrite = JSON.stringify(user);
    fs.writeFile('./database.json', dataToWrite, (err) => { // the second parameter is missing!
      res.send(user.gold); // send a response to the client
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: but this will delete the whole content of the file? there will be just left `{"id":2312,"name":"Garzec","gold":3}`

Comment: @peterHasemann I did not see logical flaw in the code, was more specific about argument which was suppose to be passed as `DATA`...